# push array in class is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

this is summary of my code.
Frame is defined as

```
export type Frame = {
  changes: readonly vscode.TextDocumentContentChangeEvent[];
  selections: readonly vscode.Selection[];
};
```

**record.ts**

```
export default class SomeClass {
  private timeout: NodeJS.Timer | undefined = undefined;
  private _text = Frame[][] = [];

  constructor() {
    // Do some constructor
  }

  private onDidChange() {
    this.triggerSave();
  }

  private triggerSave() {
    if (this.timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.timeout = undefined;
    }

    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.save, 500);
  }

  private save() {
    this._text.push('__someframething__');
    console.log(this._text);
    // Output: undefined
  }
}
```

on save method, _text must be **Frame Thing**

But on the console, it's undefined.
what's wrong with it?

Full code on my gist
[record.ts](https://gist.github.com/lill74/234b67c3d01932b58a28d30b2eedfc81)
[buffer.ts](https://gist.github.com/lill74/dd30386b8a9095f16e770d99c734e08e)

Comment: `private _text = Frame[][] = []` did you mean to use a colon instead of the first equals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

this.save = this.save.bind(this) in your constructor.

greetings